# Remove conflicted branch in git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am using git for my projects, and some days ago I commited the same changes on on two clients. then I pushed both commits to the central repo. now I have a branch with conflict:

```
git branch
* master
  master (In Konflikt stehende Kopie von Matthias 2011-05-24)
```

<sub>For non German speaking users: `master (conflicted copy by Matthias 2011-05-24)`</sub>

How can I delete this conflicted master branch? Both contain exactly the same data, except for the commit message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
git branch -D "master (In Konflikt stehende Kopie von Matthias 2011-05-24)"
```

The `-D` flag forces the deletion even when the current branch is not a descendant of the conflicted branch.

Comment: oh, that was too easy. Sorry!didn't think about this being the name of the branch!